# App Crash Due to Memory Issue on 'GET' request for many objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a method that retrieved a lot of data and stores it into an array, and then passes it to the completion handler:

```
[edcs getClinicalPatientDataWithDictionaryForPatientID:participant.participantNum withStartDate:pastDate withEndDate:currentDate completionBlock:^(NSDictionary *jsonDict) {
    if ([jsonDict[@"status"] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
        if (jsonDict[@"body"]) {
            NSMutableArray *body = [NSMutableArray  arrayWithObject:jsonDict[@"body"]];
            if (body) {
                // Query all measurements
                for (NSArray *jsonArray in body) {
                    for (NSDictionary *measurementDict in jsonArray) {
                        // Separate Hydration measurements
                        if (![body.description containsString:@"<null>"]) {
                            if (measurementDict) {
                                if ([[measurementDict objectForKey:@"MeasureUnitID"] isEqualToString:@"Cups"]) {
                                    [cupsPastYearTotalArray addObject:measurementDict];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
         completionBlock(cupsPastYearTotalArray);
```

The issue is that my array "cupsPastYearTotalArray" has over 500 objects so my projects memory usage goes up to 600 MB and then crashes.

What is the best way for me to manage all this data so that my app doens't crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [autoreleasepool block](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html).

```
 [edcs getClinicalPatientDataWithDictionaryForPatientID:participant.participantNum withStartDate:pastDate withEndDate:currentDate completionBlock:^(NSDictionary *jsonDict) {
        if ([jsonDict[@"status"] isEqualToString:@"200"] && jsonDict[@"body"]) {
            NSMutableArray *body = [NSMutableArray  arrayWithObject:jsonDict[@"body"]];
            for (NSArray *jsonArray in body) {
                @autoreleasepool {
                    for (NSDictionary *measurementDict in jsonArray) {
                        @autoreleasepool {
                            if (![body.description containsString:@"<null>"] && measurementDict && [[measurementDict objectForKey:@"MeasureUnitID"] isEqualToString:@"Cups"]) {
                                [cupsPastYearTotalArray addObject:measurementDict];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        completionBlock(cupsPastYearTotalArray)
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

"body.description" gives you a description of body, suitable for debugging. You should never, ever use this outside a debug statement. Most likely you want to check for [NSNull null] somewhere. And you definitely don't want to repeat that check again and again in a loop. That description that you calculate is *big*. Puneet's help avoids running out of memory, it doesn't stop your code wasting CPU time and battery life by *producing* 600+ MB of data.